# What is the difference between `on` and `to` in AppleScript handler declaration

Tags: applescript

What is the difference between `on` and `to` in AppleScript handler declaration? When to use one or the other?

For example the following handlers do the same:

```
on demo1()
   return 1
end demo1

to demo2()
   return 1
end demo2
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between them. Both `on` and `to` are acceptable.

From [Using Handlers/Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/UseHandlersFunctions.html)

> Listing 13-3 shows a variation of the handler in Listing 13-1, which uses the to prefix instead of on. Either syntax is acceptable.

From [Handler Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH7g)

```
( on | to ) handlerName ¬
   [ [ of | in ] directParamName ] ¬
   [ ASLabel userParamName ]... ¬
   [ given userLabel:userParamName [, userLabel:userParamName ]...]
      [ statement ]...
end [ handlerName ]
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. Good to know - although I can't grasp why there are two keywords for the same thing.

Comment: There are two words so that you can form English-like constructions more easily, depending on what it is that you are doing.

For example, `to quit:` conveys a slightly different English-syntax meaning than `on quit`. Saying `on quit` implies receiving a `quit` signal, where saying `to quit` might be interpreted as more accurately described by saying something like "To quit, find the entry in the Force Quit menu". Similarly for the second line in the reference template above, where `of` and `in` are synonyms, use whichever sounds better or more meaningful to you in context.